# Возможна ли иерархия со статическими классами C#

Tags: c#

Подскажите, как можно сделать правильную иерархию классов. Конкретный пример: У меня есть два класса сортировки одного типа(у меня это быстрая сортировка),  и у них похожие реализации(у каждого по три метода и только один отличается).
Так как это классы сортировки - они статические, ибо экземпляры не надо. Можно ли создать класс-родитель с уже написанными двумя одинаковыми методами и шаблоном под третий метод, который можно будет реализовать у каждого класса отдельно? Вот примерный код класса сортировки, таких будет два:

```
 static class QuickSort
{
    static public List<int> Sort(List<int> array, int indexMin, int indexMax) //Первый одинаковый метод
    {
        //вызов Partition
    }

    static private int Partition(List<int> array, int indexMin, int indexMax) //метод, с разной реализацией
    {
        //...
    }

    static public void Swap(List<int> list, int indexA, int indexB) //Второй одинаковый метод
    {
        //...
    }

}
```

Comment: `Так как это классы сортировки - они статические` я не понял связи здесь. Можете пояснить?

Comment: Согласен, не обосновано сказал. Смотря на библиотечные классы сортировки, я заметил, что там эти  методы статические.
Ну и плюс не надо создавать объекты. Т.е. статические методы и не надо создавать объект -> Эти классы должны быть статическими. Возможно, есть более правильное решение

Comment: Полиморфизма у статики нет, вы не можете со статикой использовать `virtual` и `override`.